# How could I get the number of dates that fit a given month in a javascript array of momentjs dates?

Tags: javascript, arrays, momentjs

I have a specific array of momentjs dates like this:

Schema:

```
tasks.data: [ 
     {startDate: Mon Nov 25 2013 20:32:28 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)},
     {startDate: Tue Nov 26 2013 20:32:28 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)},
     {startDate: Wed Nov 27 2013 20:32:28 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)},
     {startDate: Thu Nov 28 2013 20:32:28 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)},
     {startDate: Fri Nov 29 2013 20:32:28 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)}
]
```

rest of the data..

```
Mon Nov 25 2013 20:32:28 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
Tue Nov 26 2013 20:32:28 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
Wed Nov 27 2013 20:32:28 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
Thu Nov 28 2013 20:32:28 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
Fri Nov 29 2013 20:32:28 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
Sat Nov 30 2013 20:32:28 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
Sun Dec 01 2013 20:32:28 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
Mon Dec 02 2013 20:32:28 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
Tue Dec 03 2013 20:32:28 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
Wed Dec 04 2013 20:32:28 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
Thu Dec 05 2013 20:32:28 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
Fri Dec 06 2013 20:32:28 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
```

Give say the Month of November 2013, how can I determine the count of dates that fall within that month and year? As my array has dates that span over 3 years.

My ultimate goal us to use the count in creating a sort of like gantt chart and use colspan="" on the month header based on the number of dates.

The information I have is the array of dates and the month and year I want to check.

Something like

```
return GetDateCounts(Month, Year){
   return dateArry.map.indexOf(moment(startDate).month() == Month && moment(startDate).year() == Year)
}
```

Edit: with no duplicates.

Example:

If I have dates from Nov 21st-30th 2013, that should be count of 9, or 9 days.
If I have two repeating dates for the 21st, I would want to ignore that and only still have a count of 9.

Comment: Except the dates needs to be quoted you seem on the right track

Answer (score 0):

Ok I managed out this convoluted function that works, but I'm sure there's got to be a better/fast, less lines of codes way to do this. Note I had to flatten my complex object cause I couldn't figure out how to loop through data.startDate, so I created a flat array of the dates in vm.dates.

If someone can come up with a better way I'll give the answer to them.

```
            var uniqueDates = [];
            var count = 0;
            var unique = false;
            vm.dates.forEach(function (date) {
                if (moment(date).month() == month && moment(date).year() == year) {
                    unique = true;

                    //Attempt to find previous "day" in unique array list
                    uniqueDates.forEach(function (uniqueDate) {
                        if (moment(uniqueDate).date() == moment(date).date()) {
                            //If found set Unique to False
                            unique = false;
                        }
                    });

                    if (unique == true) {
                        //If Unique count
                        count++;
                        //and add found date to the Unique List
                        uniqueDates.push(date);
                        unique = false;
                    }

                };
            });
           return count;
```